# scopes on chain: node distance not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, scoping

I have defined a few commands that each output a bunch of TikZ nodes that, combined, conceptually represent a single node/object. In order for the generated nodes to be treated as a cohesive whole, I wrap them in a scope.

- `\instruction{identifier base}{text L}{text R}{box style}{length style}{scope style}`
- `\twoPInstruction{identifier base}{text L}{textR}{box style}{len1}{len3}{scope style}`

With these commands, I want to create [chain diagrams](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/diagram-chains/) where these colorful instruction blocks are put next to each other.
**All I'm getting is this overlapping drawing:**
[image]

**But I want them aligned adjacently:** (something like this)
[image]
*(the gray outline, and black box surrounding my renderings is caused by texmaker's preview)*

I have tried adjusting TikZ's `node distance` style, but whatever distance I chose, I cannot get the orange box off of the blue one.

Here's my (super long) MWE. Most of it's styling, though; The interesting stuff happens in `\newcommand`s and at the end near `\begin{tikzpicture}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,positioning,calc,matrix,fit,shapes.miscs,scopes,chains}

\tikzstyle{base}=[
    font={\sffamily\bfseries},
]
\tikzstyle{box}=[
    base,
    rounded rectangle,
    draw=black,
    inner sep=0.5ex,
]
\tikzstyle{boxL}=[
    box,
    rounded rectangle right arc=none,
]
\tikzstyle{boxR}=[
    box,
    rounded rectangle left arc=none,
]
\tikzstyle{inner}=[
    base,
    inner sep=0,
    node distance=0,
    line width=0,
]
\tikzstyle{innerL}=[
    inner,
    font={\small\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}},
]
\tikzstyle{innerR}=[
    inner,
    font={\small\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}},
]
\tikzstyle{innerLine}=[
    ->,
    dashed,
    dash pattern=on 0.25ex off 0.125ex,
    decorate,
    decoration={
        snake,
        amplitude=0.18ex,
        segment length=1ex,
        post length=0.5ex
    },
]
\tikzstyle{hop}=[
    ->,
    out=45,
    in=135,
    dashed,
    dash pattern=on 0.25ex off 0.125ex,
]
\tikzstyle{sep}=[
    inner,
    minimum width=1ex,
]

\tikzstyle{blue}=[
    fill=cyan,
]
\tikzstyle{orange}=[
    fill=orange,
]
\tikzstyle{len1}=[
    inner,
    text width=6ex,
]
\tikzstyle{len2}=[
    inner,
    text width=13ex,
]
\tikzstyle{len3}=[
    inner,
    text width=19ex,
]
\tikzstyle{len4}=[
    inner,
    text width=25ex,
]

\pgfdeclarelayer{box}
\pgfdeclarelayer{text}
\pgfsetlayers{box,text,main}

\newcommand{\baseInstruction}[7]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, box style, length style, scope style
{[#7]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{text}%box contents
        \node[#6] (#1 Skel) {};
        \node[innerL, right=of #1 Skel.base west, anchor=base west] (#1 SkelL) {#2};
        \node[innerR, left=of #1 Skel.base east, anchor=base east] (#1 SkelR) {#3};
        \node[inner, fit=(#1 SkelL.north east)(#1 SkelR.south west)] (#1 Between1) {};
        \node[inner, fit=(#1 SkelL.south east)(#1 SkelR.north west)] (#1 Between2) {};
        \node[inner, fit=(#1 Between1)(#1 Between2)] (#1 Between) {};
        \node[inner, fit=(#1 SkelL)(#1 SkelR)] (#1 Contents) {}; %needed for attaching arrows to
        \draw[innerLine] ($(#1 Between.west) + (0.2ex,0)$) -- ($(#1 Between.east) - (0.2ex,0)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{box}%box outlines
        \node[#5, #4, fit=(#1 SkelL)(#1 SkelR)] (#1) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
}

\newcommand{\instruction}[6]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, length style, scope style
    \baseInstruction{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{box}{#5}{#6}
}

\newcommand{\instructionL}[6]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, length style, scope style
    \baseInstruction{#1L}{#2}{#3}{#4}{boxL}{#5}{#6}
}

\newcommand{\instructionR}[6]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, length style, scope style
    \baseInstruction{#1R}{#2}{#3}{#4}{boxR}{#5}{#6}
}

\newcommand{\twoPInstruction}[7]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, length style L, length style R, scope style
{[#7]
    \instructionL{#1}{#2}{\vphantom{#3}}{#4}{#5}{}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{text}%box contents   
        \node[sep, right=of #1L Skel.base east] (#1 Sep) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}    
    \instructionR{#1}{\vphantom{#2}}{#3}{#4}{#6, right=of #1 Sep}{}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{text}
        \draw ($(#1L Between.east) + (0,0.3ex)$) edge[hop] ($(#1R Between.west) + (0,0.3ex)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain,
    node distance=10cm,
    every child node/.style={on chain,join},
    every join/.style={->}
]
\instruction{a}{a}{X}{blue}{len2}{}
\twoPInstruction{b}{b}{Y}{orange}{len1}{len3}{}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `node distance` sets the default distance when you use the `positioning` keys for placing nodes using relative positions (such as `left=of a`), and not by using absolute placement as you do here

Comment: Also if you want to use the `{[style]...}` shorthand for scope you need to include the library `scopes`

Comment: I added the `scopes` library now. I've also updated my `tikzpicture` to use the chain library. The result is still the same though.

Comment: If I am not wrong in `\baseInstruction` you position all the "sub"-nodes relative to the one created in `\node[#6] (#1 Skel) {};` which, itself, is not positioned relatively to any other node (unless of course you specify otherwise in `#6`, which you don't).
So, the two "main" nodes you create are not positioned one relatively to the other so the `positioning`/`chain` keys have no effect. Am I missing something?

Comment: where is the `node-families` located?

Comment: @derabbink also, the `every child node` applies to nodes created with the `child` path action that constructs trees, which you do not use here so it gets discarded; the effect is that no node gets the `on chain` option

Comment: Indeed, I am building each block around `\node[#6] (#1 Skel) {};`
Also, even if I add `{on chain,join}` as `#6`/`#7` of `\instruction`/`\twoPInstruction`, nothing changes to the output.

Comment: I would expect each scope to behave like any other node. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @derabbink no it is not, a scope is just installing the keys in its options to the environment of the code in its body, but nothing more! In my answer I suggest you may try using nested `tikzpictures` which does what you are trying to accomplish with scopes.

Comment: I have [tried it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152804/31877), but it does not work reliably yet. Hopefully you can spot my mistakes again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@Bordaigorl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36686/bordaigorl)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152685/31877) and [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152672/scopes-on-chain-node-distance-not-working?noredirect=1#comment348517_152672), I have wrapped the body of `\instruction` and `\twoPInstruction` in nodes and tikzpictures.

```
\newcommand{\baseInstruction}[7]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, box style, length style, scope style
{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{text}%box contents
        \node[#6] (#1 Skel) {};
        \node[innerL, right=of #1 Skel.base west, anchor=base west] (#1 SkelL) {#2};
        \node[innerR, left=of #1 Skel.base east, anchor=base east] (#1 SkelR) {#3};
        \node[inner, fit=(#1 SkelL.north east)(#1 SkelR.south west)] (#1 Between1) {};
        \node[inner, fit=(#1 SkelL.south east)(#1 SkelR.north west)] (#1 Between2) {};
        \node[inner, fit=(#1 Between1)(#1 Between2)] (#1 Between) {};
        \node[inner, fit=(#1 SkelL)(#1 SkelR)] (#1 Contents) {}; %needed for attaching arrows to
        \draw[innerLine] ($(#1 Between.west) + (0.2ex,0)$) -- ($(#1 Between.east) - (0.2ex,0)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{box}%box outlines
        \node[#5, #4, fit=(#1 SkelL)(#1 SkelR)] (#1 Box) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}}

\newcommand{\instruction}[6]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, length style, scope style
\node [#6] (#1) {\tikz{
    \baseInstruction{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{box}{#5}{}
}};
}

\newcommand{\instructionL}[6]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, length style, scope style
    \baseInstruction{#1L}{#2}{#3}{#4}{boxL}{#5}{#6}
}

\newcommand{\instructionR}[6]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, length style, scope style
    \baseInstruction{#1R}{#2}{#3}{#4}{boxR}{#5}{#6}
}

\newcommand{\twoPInstruction}[7]{% id-base, text L, text R, color style, length style L, length style R, scope style
\node [#7] (#1) {\tikz{
    \instructionL{#1}{#2}{\vphantom{#3}}{#4}{#5}{}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{text}%box contents   
        \node[sep, right=of #1L Skel.base east] (#1 Sep) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}    
    \instructionR{#1}{\vphantom{#2}}{#3}{#4}{#6, right=of #1 Sep}{}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{text}
        \draw[hop] ($(#1L Between.east) + (0,0.3ex)$) to[hop] ($(#1R Between.west) + (0,0.3ex)$);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}};
}
```

[image: reverse order]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, node distance=5ex, every join/.style={->},]
\twoPInstruction{b}{b}{Y}{orange}{len1}{len3}{on chain, join}
\instruction{a}{a}{X}{blue}{len2}{on chain, join}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But reversing `a` and `b` initially gave me an error on the line of the `\twoPInstruction`: "! Package pgf Error: No shape named chain-2 is known." ... "l.139 ...b}{Y}{orange}{len1}{len3}{on chain, join}"
To fix this, I had to get rid of the `edge` in `twoPInstruction`, as this interferes with the chain library. Instead, I now use `to[hop]`. N.B. that I'm using the `hop` style twice in one line (because I'm lazy); half of the style keys apply to the `\draw` part of the line, while the other half applies to the `\to` part.

[image: normal order]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, node distance=5ex, every join/.style={->},]
\instruction{a}{a}{X}{blue}{len2}{on chain, join}
\twoPInstruction{b}{b}{Y}{orange}{len1}{len3}{on chain, join}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

PS: I also eradicated the group style (`[#7]`) from the `\baseInstruction` to avoid warnings in the log.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to include the `scopes` library for the scope shorthands to work properly.

Second, `node distance` only works for nodes placed using the `positioning` keys, such as `right=of a`, which you do not use here to position the two main nodes relatively to each other.

Therefore the quickest fix to the code (after including `scopes`) is to manually shift the second node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \instruction{a}{a}{X}{blue}{len2}{}
  \twoPInstruction{b}{b}{Y}{orange}{len1}{len3}{xshift=2cm}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also, you may consider using multipart nodes instead of manually drawing the shapes.

Another option is using nested `tikzpicture`s by having just two nodes `\node (a) {\tikz{...}};` and `\node[right=of a] (b) {\tikz{...}};` so that you can use the two "logical" nodes as "modules", which would make the use of `fit` unnecessary.

Comment: I have tried this, but I still get an error. I wrote up [an answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152804/31877) that shows my modified code and corresponding errors